# Get request not the same decoded

Tags: json, perl, request

Hi all i'm new at perl but i have few experience in other language.
So i made a simple code that get JSON file from internet here a telegram bot, but when i display it i got no probleme but when i decoded it with dedcode_json i dont have at all the same output :///

Here the output of the server :

```
Received reply: {"ok":true,"result":{"id":0000,"first_name":"[MAGA]"}}
```

and now the output of the decoded anwser :

```
$VAR1 = {
      'ok' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ),
      'result' => {
                    'id' => 0000,
                    'username' => 'MAGA_bot',
                    'first_name' => '[MAGA]'
                  }
    };
```

how can i just get the 'result' part of the decoded json ?

here my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $destination = "http://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/getMe";

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $destination);
my $succes;
my $json;

my $resp = $ua->request($req);
if ($resp->is_success) {
    my $message = $resp->decoded_content;
    print "Received reply: $message\n";
    $succes = "yes";
    $json = $message;
} else {
    print "HTTP POST error code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
    print "HTTP POST error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
}

print "Encoding the JSON file \n";
if ($succes eq "yes") {
    my $decoded_json = decode_json($json);
    print Dumper($decoded_json);
} elsif ($succes ne "yes") {
    print "Parsing JSON failed\n";
}
```

Comment: In what way is the decoded JSON different/wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since the decoded JSON is converted into a Perl hash reference in this case, you access it as such:

```
my $result = $decoded_json->{result};
print "$result->{first_name}\n";
```

Output:

```
[MAGA]
```

Comment: thanks a lot its working ! and what should i change for getting all this output :            'result' => {
                    'id' => 0000,
                    'username' => 'MAGA_bot',
                    'first_name' => '[MAGA]'
                  }   ???

Comment: `$result->{id}; $result->{username};`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display part of a complex data structure, then just print that part of the data structure.

```
print Dumper $decoded_json->{result};
```